# Как добавить отдельный php код в php-curl?

Tags: php, кодировка, curl

Всем привет

Как добавить html/php код с произвольным добавлением POST параметров не нарушая обработке скрипта (интеграции)

Доспустим у нас есть код:

```
$json_array = [
    "pid" => "tv1hxs",
    "offerId" => 111,
    "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
    "lastname" => $_POST['lastname'],
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "phone" => $_POST['full_phone'],
    "country" => $_POST['country'],
    "ref" => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
    "ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
]; 
$body = json_encode($json_array);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin.neogara.com/api/lid');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ( file_exists('text.txt')){
    $file_content = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('text.txt'));
    unlink('text.txt');
}
$file_content['users'][] = array('user'=>$_POST);
file_put_contents('text.txt',json_encode($file_content));
if($http_code == 200){
    if (empty($response['cabinetUrl'])) {
        header('Location: success.html');
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $response['cabinetUrl']);
    }
}else{
    echo $response['message'];
}
```

Нам нужно добавить код пикселя фб в обработчика, чтобы тот отбивал конверсии, не нарушая выполнение скрипта

Вот код пикселя

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '<?php echo ($_GET['fb']) ;?>');
  fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<?php echo ($_GET['fb']) ;?>&ev=Lead&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Заранее благодарочка!!

Comment: То есть, вы пытаетесь выполнить непонятно какую js на другом ресурсе посредством curl?

Comment: Нужно добавить пиксель с уникальным post или get в php curl, это как то должно принтоваться не нарушая обработки кода

Comment: curl отправляет запросы на адрес, ваш пиксель это скрипт для страницы.. Вы непонятно что пытаетесь сделать - так не надо и нельзя делать